# HTML5 Datepicker with disabled dates not working in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker, angular-reactive-forms

I want to disable past dates in date-picker (HTML5).When I use date-picker without any conditions (spontaneously) the disabled dates are working.

If I use date-picker with conditions it won't work. I used jQuery to append the today date to "min" attribute of the date element (using jQuery with Angular is bad practice). because I couldn't find how to access/append the attribute of the date element using form control typescript. (Ex:formname.get('formcontrolName')....)

I want the date-picker should work with conditions.

[Source code](https://github.com/jeyamaal/HTML5DatePickerBug)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind datepicker's `min` attribute to the component's property. Here's a relevant part of working example (be aware that the value must be assigned to the given property in the constructor because `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook is called to late):

### HTML

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" [min]="today" id="applyDate1" formControlName="applyDate1"/>
```

### TypeScript

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  public personalForm: FormGroup;
  public today;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    const currentDate:Date = new Date();
    let dd:any = currentDate.getDate();
    let mm:any = currentDate.getMonth()+1;
    let yyyy:any = currentDate.getFullYear();

    if(dd<10) {
        dd = '0'+dd
    } 

    if(mm<10) {
        mm = '0'+mm
    } 

    this.today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;

    ...
  }

 ...

}
```

Comment: let dd:number should be changed to dd:any (cannot concatenate with string) same as mm and yyyy.